# Appeal review ban

Tags: bug, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I have been banned for review for 7 days (really harsh) for actually making a correct review of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5789984#./5789984?&_suid=141094458349008970139738711909).

Please can somebody explain, why? I see other user with higher reputation has given the answer a <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> review and that is the exact same review I had given.

This has happened 2nd time in last 2 days. Please let me know if its possible to correct this obvious bug in review system!

Comment: Any chance of a transcript of the answer for the sub-10k users? That question doesn't seem great to be honest, I'd have voted to close it if I was able to...

Comment: That answer doesn't _"Look OK"_ at all.

Comment: [*"Learn to love that Skip button."*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153279/165773 "quote source")

Comment: Where did you see high rep users involved in this review audit?

Comment: You could see everything but that? If you click the above link you will see a certain David Arenberg has given it a review of "Looks OK"

Comment: That's the reason he failed his audit too. Even 10K users make mistakes.

Comment: Not sure if language plays a part in this, but it is totally clear from us native speakers this is 100% spam.  Any time you see someone suggesting a product in an answer it's most likely spam.  And, if a honest answer, is still not acceptable here.  Both the question and answer need to go in that case.

Comment: In most cases, answers to bad questions are also bad. Software recommendation is already the indicator here, whether the post itself is a spam or not.

Answer (score 21):

The original post was:

> I had some experience with migration from Interbase to Mssqlserver as well. We had quite a massive scope and many stored procedures. We decided to start the interaction with [COMPANY X SOFTWARE]. It appeared to be a good decision: their product [X] migrates data as well as SQL-objects. Moreover, the tool can be customized. For the migration of SQL objects I would definitely recommend this tool.

That answer was just spamming the company name and product without disclosure (apparently this user was linked to that company because he posted this multiple times). You said this post was okay. That's why you failed. Also, you were review banned for multiple failed audits. This is just one of them.

Comment: Ok but still if I strictly go by SO rules then the question should have been flagged in the first place for recommending to find a tool or library! In this case the answer is not really off topic unless I misunderstood something but believe the question is! Am I missing something?

Comment: @Nilesh yes, the question should be closed. Thank you for bringing it to our attention/

Comment: Indeed. The question should be closed, but in the mean time, answers are posted and reviewed. The problem isn't in the answer or question being off-topic. The answer is SPAM!

Comment: @Nilesh: It had already a close vote against it, and now it is closed.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for asserting! does that result in review of ban? :-)

Comment: @Nilesh I doubt it, your review was still incorrect...

Comment: @Nilesh - no, as others have pointed out the answer was clearly not OK.

Comment: I don't understand this! I am asked to review an answer to a question that should be closed. The answer does try to recommend a tool (technically). These questions are not allowed as per SO rules. So how is giving an OK to an answer that actually was is incorrect. Disappointing and discouraging for someone who tries to deligently come here and help people!

Comment: You let obvious spam through. What is unclear on that?

Comment: @Nilesh, you have some nerve. Not only did you give a positive review to utter spam, but you keep insisting you did nothing wrong and are now attacking the people who are trying to explain the problem to you. It doesn't look like you're learning anything from this incident. A seven-day ban now looks insufficient in retrospect.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I believe you should read everything end to end before jumping to conclusion. I believe most of the guys here have that habit. I never said that I did nothing wrong. I was trying to question method and a harsh ban. And you talk about attack I believe its other way around. Instead of guiding(barring @ChrisF) you guys are using the kind of language that doesn't really go with your reputation. As I said with that attitude you would drive more ppl away than encourage. Don't get judgemental about how long the ban should be.

Comment: You say you are mistreated, pointing to other users making the same mistake. You have failed too much review audits, and that's why you are review banned. You can learn from it by paying more attention next time.

Comment: @Nilesh Maybe the language others are using seems ruder to you than it really is. From my perspective the language and discussion here seems perfectly reasonable, until you started accusing Patrick. It may be terse, but it's perfectly factual. Let's all let this go, will ya?

Comment: The asker and answerer were the same person. It was complete baldfaced spam.

Comment: @meagar: Are you sure? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Wow, I was looking at the question's editor, not the author. You'd think I could tell them apart by now.

Comment: @meagar You'd think! Apparently, you'd be wrong! ;)  (I've done very similar things, very often!)

Answer (score 16):

[Patrick Hofman's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271515/237838) covers anything I'd want to say there, but there's another aspect of your question I'd like to address: The idea that a 7-day review ban is *harsh*.

It simply isn't.

7 days isn't really any time at all. Many users go seven days between visits to the site. (Ok; not me, for sure! Nor, probably, any more than .0001% of Meta users!). It's just time to let you think about things, and ask questions like this. (No comment on where it's gone *since asking*...)

But here's the most important point I have: Reviewing isn't a vital service the site provides to you. It's something you are doing to help improve the site, but you can still do the core things it's here for: Ask and answer questions, vote, comment, etc. All you lose is *one of many* ways you can contribute to making the site better, and specifically to that point, the review ban was put in place because the system believes you need to improve how you do that.

So, I think "harsh" is just not at all accurate for something like this.