# Review banned over incorrect audit item

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I have five gold badges for reviews. I have over 5,700 reviews under my belt. I also have the gold Marshal badge for over 500 helpful flags.

I was temporarily banned from reviewing for deciding that no action was needed on a workaround solution that had the same solution as another upvoted question; here's the audit item that led to the ban:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6024600

Here's the question:

[after installing magento cannot login admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415958/after-installing-magento-cannot-login-admin)

According to this asked, answered, and accepted Stackoverflow question, it's the right answer: [Why I can not login to magento backend using google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328366/why-i-can-not-login-to-magento-backend-using-google-chrome/15181463?noredirect=1#15181463)

**It is legitimately a possible answer as a workaround**, and even if you disagree, **[it's not my job as a reviewer to judge its correctness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031/239121)**, rather it's to carefully review the answer ensure that it's an actual answer. Which I did, and it is. (No it did not strike me as particularly good, but reviewers should presume that those with more domain knowledge would vote it down if it were incorrect.) There are many highly voted answers on Stackoverflow that are the same length, to criticize me for not rejecting it as a comment is foolish. I make many flags and comments requesting more elaboration about non-answers and borderlines that are comments. This was not a comment. It was an answer. A terse one. Perhaps even shallow. But it did not demand a comment from me. It was an answer. And I used my discretion as a reviewer to let it go.

Here's the guidelines for reviewing Late Answers on Meta Stackexchange:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031/239121

Is this right, and if not, what should I do?

Should I be penalized for taking a correct action that others screwed up?

---

**Current Conclusion**

My conclusion is that I did the right thing, given the evidence I had, in spite of my ignorance of magento and the appropriateness of using a different browser as a workaround to admin it, which was an upvoted solution. There was nothing further for me to comment (would I challenge it as incorrect?). There was no reason for me to downvote it (someone else, perhaps the asker, had *upvoted* a nearly identical answer). Flagging it would imply I believed it to be either spam, offensive, not an actual answer, very low quality, or that it otherwise required the attention of a moderator. I thought it could be borderline low quality, but for integrity's sake, I took none of these actions, in spite of evidence that it was an audit (as I could not find the actual answer on the page).

In spite of my naysayers's confidence, I did the right thing.

Comment: Also, you don't get review banned for just one failure. It takes a few.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I've done thousands of reviews. Incorrect audit items happen.

Comment: If I am not knowledgeable in the area in the post, I won't review it, and mere familiarity is not enough.  Use a filter to only review in your favorite tags, or select "skip" for those that are outside of your areas.

Comment: That's an interesting criteria. Is it in the guidelines? I haven't seen it so far. I wonder how much reviewing would get done if everyone followed that criteria. But it's certainly an easy out for my detractors.

Comment: I don't know if it is in the guidelines, but it is what I do.  If you know the subject material, you'll also know if something is or is not an answer (etc.).  If I don't feel qualified to vote on a post, I also don't consider myself qualified to review it.

Comment: Your review action was incorrect. That was not an answer, and you should not have allowed it through the review with no action taken. You don't get review banned for a single review, so apparently you've failed others in a short period of time. If I asked my auto mechanic what was wrong with my Ford vehicle and the answer was "You should buy a Honda", I'd be very unlikely to go back to that repair shop. If you asked a programming question about C++, and got an answer back that you should use VB.Net instead, would you consider that a valid answer? I think not.

Comment: @KenWhite Ah, but it was an answer, and brashly asserting it wasn't doesn't make it not so. Feel free to inspect my review history of over 5700 reviews and contrast it with that of others.

Comment: @AaronHall Are you actually going to listen to anyone? The question is on -7, nobody has commented or answered saying your action was correct, and the review audit system has banned you from reviewing for a short time. Do any of these things make you think you might actually have got this one wrong?

Comment: @worldofjr There's actually a mix of up and down votes on this. I did the right thing, and a person with integrity doesn't determine ethics by sticking his finger in the wind.

Comment: It was *not an answer*. It might have been a dumb comment, but it was not an answer, and if that's the quality of "answer* you're accepting in your reviews, you're doing no one here a favor. "Brashly asserting" that you were right does not make it so, and bragging about 5700+ reviews doesn't change the fact that you made the wrong decision in this case and apparently in sufficient others to warrant a review ban.

Comment: @AaronHall Oh my word. Why bother asking the question in the first place? Fine, 3 people have upvoted (which doesn't mean they agree with your review) and 10 people have downvoted. I have a similar record in the opposite direction on my answer. If you want an answer from a moderator, go ahead and flag the question (or my answer if you like) with the *other* flag and explain what action you want.

Comment: I'm quite proud to be a part of the greatest programming Q&A site on Earth, and thanks for the input guys, I promise I'll take your opinions on the matter under consideration. ;)

Comment: Why the hell is that question still open?  Go, now, VTC.  Fly, you fools!

Comment: +1 Good point, the question is a dupe. But the workaround answers were incorrectly deleted, even if they weren't particularly great.

Answer (score 7):

There's no other way to say this; **you are wrong**.

That answer does not answer the (admittedly, poor) question. It is clear that there is a problem with the OP's set-up which is causing a problem in Chrome, and the OP might be setting up the system for someone else who uses Chrome. The OP also explicitly said it was a problem in Chrome, so presumably he already knew he could log in using a different browser.

It's not an obvious non-answer like "I don't know what you mean", but answers should solve the problem, not just avoid it. This answer would have been a valid comment, not a valid answer.

Nevertheless, the reason why you failed the audit is because you took no action. You could have commented saying the answer was poor, downvoted the answer, or flagged as "not an answer" or "very low quality" in order to pass the audit. **Downvoting would have been enough**, and you would have automatically passed the audit.

Just to reiterate, you failed the audit because you clicked **No Action Needed**. Some action was needed on that post, even if you don't think that it should be flagged as "not an answer".

---

Since you have edited your question, I'll add this to my answer;

Just because you have the Marshal badge and raised a good number of helpful flags, doesn't mean you have any more authority than anyone else on reviewing. I will state again ... **you failed the audit because you decided that no action was needed, when it was clear that at least some action was required**. If you don't agree with me that it was not an answer, then that's fine; but it was clearly a low quality answer which as a minimum you should have downvoted.

If you posted a question saying I've got a problem with my website in Chrome, but it works fine in Firefox and IE, and I answered with "*Don't use Chrome then.*", do you think that would be an acceptable solution? Surely not! I would expect that my answer would be flagged as "very low quality" or "not an answer".

Nevertheless, review bans are only temporary. They are designed to make you think again about your reviewing. Take a look at [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271539/3899908) from **Andrew Barber** (a moderator) about attitudes to reviewing. Take heed!

Comment: By the way, I've just flagged the other answer that only said "Use Firefox". Like I said, it's a legitimate comment, but not a legitimate answer.

Comment: *Follow up*: ... and now that flagged answer has been deleted, so clearly the community agrees with me!

Comment: That answer had an upvote when I saw it, and no it did not come from me. A workaround is not clearly a bad answer. Any marginal answer up for review will get deleted. Clearly this is evidence of that, it is certainly not evidence of your unanimity of support in the reviewer community.

Comment: So one person upvoted it, *shrugs*. Anyway, workarounds can be good answers, but just saying "use a different browser" is very clearly not.